# Water-cooling system vs fans installation

Tags: performance, fan, water-cooling

I'd like to buy a workstation, but I'm hesitating between one with water cooling system and an installation on multiple ventilators. Could anyone be able to explain to me what is the better choice between those two devices (and the difference)? (reliability, performance, durability, price)

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I'd like, if possible, a full answer to this question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Welcome to superuser. Please have a look on our [help center](http://superuser.com/help) to learn what type off questions you may ask here. Your current question is off-topic for several reasons.

Comment: Where could I ask this question ?

Comment: "How long is a piece of string?" It really depends on the coolers in question and a *good* aircooler is probably as good as a closed loop cooler. Things like https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/2ggie9/discussion_air_cooling_vs_water_cooling_8_coolers/ is worth a read.

Comment: Water cooling cost more up front, and does have the possibility of leaks, which are rare. If you ask me, the biggest advantage of water cooling is the silence. Fans can be fairly quiet too, depending on their diameter and how many RPMs they run.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is pretty simple usually. Water cooling hands down offers better cooling in general.

If you don't need better cooling (say for overclocking or extending the shelf life of the CPU) then typically you don't need water cooling.

It's more of an enthusiast level upgrade that usually costs more up front.

It would help if you listed a particular CPU - some could vouch for temps if so.